# Highlight indexed words in text

Tags: indexing

In latex, upon generating an index I need a way to:

- highlight (emphasize,..) every instance of each indexed word. For example, if the word "Osmosis" is indexed, I need a way to autmatically highlight this word every time it apears in text so that the reader knows it is indexed.
- Also, How can I number the index entries so that the highlighted words take the same numbering shown in the index in the form of a superscript with a seperate numbering since I am already using (footcites and footnotes)?
- Also how can I make a hyperlink between this superscript and the index?

Comment: You can define an indexing command that does what you want to each word you index: `\newcommand{\myindex}[1]{\index{#1}{#1\textsuperscript{$\dag$}}` for example would index the word, then print it with a dagger symbol so you know it's in the index.

Comment: Hyperref will make links from the index back to the pages listed in the index (with `hyperindex` option, on by default IIRC).

Comment: I've seen this done for glossaries in textbooks ("All words followed by a dagger symbol can be found in the glossary") but otherwise I would find it very distracting as a reader, just my opinion.

Comment: @ musarithmia, I need it for every instance/repitition of the indexed word and not for the indexed word only!

Comment: The LaTeX program only alters its default behavior (putting letters on the page) when it encounters a control sequence, starting with an active character. So you could do `\newcommand{\osmosis}{\myindex{osmosis}}` using the above command, and then replace all instances of `osmosis` with `\osmosis`.

Comment: If you don't want macros for everything, you will need LuaLaTeX for this.

Comment: @TeXnician, I already am using lualatex + biblatex, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You can pre-process the file/ input buffer with callbacks, match indexed words and put `\emph` around their occurrences.